# Как исключить вывод категорий в динамическом меню bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть динамическое меню, берущее структуру из каталога. Нужно исключить оттуда несколько подкатегорий и категорий, возможно ли это стандартными средствами битрикса? Если нет, то как можно решить вопрос?

Comment: стандартными методами навряд ли. Нужно править либо компонент вывода меню, либо файл, в котором у вас собирается меню из структуры каталога.

Answer (score -1):

Решил вопрос тем, что создал доп. свойствo раздела да/нет. Вывел это свойство в меню через `component.php`. Потом прописал вывод в шаблон: если доп. свойство включено, то не выводить раздел.